# Comparison between vectors in matlab

Tags: matlab, compare

if i have A=[3 4 5 6] and B=[6 5 4] then i want to compare each value in A with all values in B, 
if this value is greater then increase counter with 1 and if this value is equal then increase another counter with 1

Comment: So, what's the expected result for your example `A` and `B`? Should it be `[0, 0, 1, 2]`? Or should it be the total sum, `3`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want an array that corresponds to the result of each value in `A`, you could do

```
arrayfun(@(x) sum(x > B), A)
```

this gives `[0, 0, 1, 2]`. If you want the total sum you would just put `sum(...)` around that:

```
sum(arrayfun(@(x) sum(x > B), A))
```

this gives `3`.

For the equal-counter, you can simply change `>` to `==`:

```
arrayfun(@(x) sum(x == B), A)
```

this gives `[0, 1, 1, 1]`.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach in comparison to `arrayfun` would be [`bsxfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html).  Though it takes a bit more memory, I'd argue that it's faster.  `arrayfun` is implicitly a `for` loop and using loops in MATLAB is usually slower than vectorized approaches.

If you want the greater than case, use the `gt` function with `bsxfun`, so:

```
>> A = [3 4 5 6];
>> B = [6 5 4];
>> sum(bsxfun(@gt, A, B.'), 1)

ans =

     0     0     1     2
```

If you want to accumulate all of the values that match the criterion, you can put another `sum` call within this `bsxfun` call:

```
>> sum(sum(bsxfun(@gt, A, B.'), 1))

ans =

     3
```

For the greater than or equal case, use `ge`:

```
>> sum(bsxfun(@ge, A, B.'), 1)

ans =

     0     1     2     3
```

For the equality case, use `eq`:

```
>> sum(bsxfun(@eq, A, B.'), 1)

ans =

     0     1     1     1
```

Again, if you want to accumulate all of the values that match the criterion, nest another `sum` call with the above results.